# .npmignore - Ignore all *.ts files but not *.d.ts

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npmignore

I am looking for a good way to ignore all .ts files in a project when I publish to NPM, I can do that by adding the following to my `.npmignore` file:

```
*.ts
```

but wait..actually I want to keep all the `.d.ts` files in my project, when I publish...

What can I add to my .npmignore file that will keep all `.d.ts` files but ignore all `.ts` files?

I assumed I have to use some form of regex to ignore all files that end with .ts that do not end with .d.ts

so the JS regex for this might look like:

```
*.\.[^d]\.ts
```

what the above regex should mean is match anything that ends with .ts that does not end with .d.ts

but of course we are stuck with what I believe to be less powerful regexes used by the OS etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the docs for [.npmignore](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) it states:

> `.npmignore` files follow the [same pattern rules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files) as `.gitignore` files:

In which case you can negate the `.d.ts` files in `.npmignore` by using `!`. For example in your `.npmignore` you simply:

```
# ignore the .ts files
*.ts

# include the .d.ts files
!*.d.ts
```

Comment: so the include will override the ignore?

Comment: Yes the `.npmignore` config simply says ignore all `.ts` (i.e. `*.ts`) and by using the apostrophe `!` your saying but do track `.d.ts` (i.e. `!*.d.ts`), even though you're ignoring the `.ts` files with the previous statement above.

Comment: Yep, note that the negation using ! has to come last as far as I can tell.

Comment: this doesn't work for local file install `"my-package": "file:../shared"` but works for local tgz file install, `npm install ../../my-package/my-package-1.1.0.tgz`